# Change the default language in Open Suse Tumbleweed

Tags: kde, locale, plasma5, yast

I installed OpenSuse Tumbleweed instead of Debian, with which I have a 25 years familiarity, on my new PC.

Now, I have problems with UTF-8, e.g., when I `cat some_file` containing UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters I see some garbage, also input methods don't work properly.

To fix the problems, e.g., I can start an XTerm like `LANG=C.utf8 xterm` and in the new XTerm everything is fine.

What I want to do is to set my `LANG` to `C.utf8` globally, but every (EVERY) guide I've found just explains how to use Yast to perform the task, and Yast lists tens of different languages but no `C`.

The configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/language` is over 100 lines and I find it confusing, and I'm not particularly confident that it's the right place to modify.

How must I `LANG=C.utf8` permanently, using Yast or without using Yast?

Comment: I don't know OpenSuse but what display manager are you using? Does it source any config files or does it have its own config? If it had `LANG` set than all of its children would inherit its value.

Comment: What is the output of the command ´locale´ in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, brute force sometimes helps. I've "grepped" into ALL the files in my home directory for `LANG=` and amid a ton of garbage I found

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep LANG= 2>/dev/null
...
./.config/plasma-localerc:LANG=C
...
$
```

I changed that to `LANG=C.utf8` (lower case, no dash), logged out and logged in and now I'm an happy guy.

So, at a system level, that is propagated e.g. to new users, you have to modify `/etc/locale.conf`, its content must be `LANG=C.utf8` (lower case, no dash), and for a user of the graphical plasma shell, that has a `LANG` environmental variable different from the system wide default, the file to modify is `~/.config/plasma-localerc`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `localectl(1)`:

```
localectl set-locale LANG=C.UTF-8
```

From the man page of the command:

> localectl may be used to query and change the system locale and
> keyboard layout settings.
>
> The system locale controls the language settings of system services
> and of the UI before the user logs in, such as the display manager, as
> well as the default for users after login.

This command will change `LANG` at your `/etc/locale.conf` file. From the man pages of `locale.conf(5)`:

> The /etc/locale.conf file configures system-wide locale settings. It
> is read at early boot by systemd(1).

Note that you will need to reboot your system in order for this change to take affect, because your window manager and the services already started with the old locale.

Comment: ① It's `C.utf8`, small letters, ② I have `LANG=C.utf8` in `/etc/locale.conf` BUT if I start an XTerm from the plasma shell, the command `env|grep -i lang` leads to `LANG=C`, so no, probably it's something KDE/Tumbleweed does when starting the graphical shell. ፨ I will add a new user, and see if the new user has the same problem or it;s some mistake I made...

Comment: I can confirm that a new vanilla user has `LANG=C.utf8`.

Comment: I can also confirm that in my dot files there is nothing that sets `LANG=C`

Comment: ① It's C.utf8, small letters AND no dash.

Comment: @gboffi, did you reboot the host? Also, you said that it works for the vanilla user. How does it work? When you `su` to him, or when did you start a new plasma shell under his account?

Comment: @gboffi Also, I assume you have plasma shell runing under your own user and not root? If you have ssh server running on your host, which `LANG` do you have after sshing to the host (even from the same host)?